# UITextView Not responding

Tags: ios, uitextview

I am using textview in my code using the below code

```
UITextView *ObservationTextView3=[[UITextView alloc]init];
ObservationTextView3.frame=CGRectMake(45, ObservationLabel3.frame.origin.y+ObservationLabel3.frame.size.height, 410, 70);
[ObservationTextView3 setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
ObservationTextView3.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
ObservationTextView3.delegate=self;
ObservationTextView3.tag=139;
ObservationTextView3.text = @"";
ObservationTextView3.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
ObservationTextView3.layer.borderColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
ObservationTextView3.layer.cornerRadius=4.0f;
[_BeverageRoutineScroll addSubview:ObservationTextView3];
```

but i am unable to make this textview respond i've tried many things but evrything goes invane.

please help me out.

Comment: Have you added UITextViewDelegete in your ViewController.h file

Comment: Your textview's frame is outside the frame of its superview.

Comment: I had try your code and it's work perfect for me

Comment: Did you added #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> in your .m file

Comment: Note: name your instances with a lowercase : observationTextView3 instead of ObservationTextView3. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourTextView];

[self.view sendSubViewToBack:yourScrollview];
```

OR

```
[self.yourScrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

[self.yourTextView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

OR

check your scrollView's Content Size and Text View Frame